# On select file upload for multiple like gmail in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have googled a lot but I am not found any clue that's why posting question

I want to upload file without submitting the form in spring MVC and file should be uploaded after file selected. 
It would be like attaching multiple file in gmail compose screen.

If you have any example or clue kindly share.

Comment: Gmail's "magic" is actually HTML5; possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522269/how-to-implement-gmail-like-file-upload-attachment-using-html-5

Comment: Other method would be to do an AJAX post, which "looks" like it's not doing a POST, but it is just doing it asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Controller Code[image]
View Code[image]
add these scripts and styles in your project
(1)jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js(I add it in Scripts folder)
(2)swfobject.js(Scripts folder)
(3)uploadify.css(content folder)
(4)uploadify.swf(Scripts folder)
(5)cancel.png(images folder)
you can add these files according to you, for further detail and download files click [here](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/376_Upload_Multiple_Files_in_ASPNet_Using_jQuery_in_GMAIL_style.aspx)

Comment: don't use screen shots. Always put code into answers/questions directly